# How to pass generic list to WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying get a complex object from my service. I have class `PackedObject` that passed fine. But when I'm trying to get `List<PackedObject>` nothing happen. 
**How to pass generic lists through WCF?**

Here is a source code:

My interface

```
 [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract=typeof(ICallbackInterface))]
public interface IManager
{
    ...

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    List<PackedObject> GetByQuery(string typeName, string query);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    PackedObject GetFirstByQuery(string typeName, string query);

    ...
}
```

Packed object

```
  [DataContract]
public class PackedObject
{
    [DataMember]
    private String _objTypeName;

    [DataMember]
    private Guid _id;

    [DataMember]
    private Dictionary<string, object> _fields = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    ...
}
```

Interface implementation:

```
    public List<PackedObject> GetByQuery(string typeName, string query)
    {
        ServerTableManager stm = getTableManager(typeName);
        List<DataRow> ldr = stm.GetByQuery(query);
        List<PackedObject> lpo = PackedObject.Pack(ldr,typeName);

        //PackedObjectList pol = new PackedObjectList(lpo);
        return lpo;
    }
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Your provided code is fine. Maybe post the method the code for `GetByQuery()`

Comment: it works fine. `List<PackedObject>` is not null.

Comment: and i have no errors.

Comment: What does "nothing happen" mean?  you say it's not null and have no errors - what's the problem?

Comment: If it "works fine" why are you asking this question. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could run and replicates the issue.

Comment: It works fine- means that `GetByQuery` method returns a valid result.
The problem is that when i'm trying to get just a single `Packedobject` from `GetFirstByQuery` all works fine, but when i use a similar method `GetByQuery` the other application that trying get this just waiting for response and nothing happen. I suppose problem is in serializing this generic list, is that true?

Comment: If your `List<PackedObject>` is not null, and it's not throwing an exception (which would happen if it was having problems deserializing), then it has to be the code that `GetByQuery()` is calling inside it's method.

Comment: `GetByQuerry` returns a valid list. Proof: http://puu.sh/g3H3D/d92dcad48c.png

Comment: Are you updating the WCF client after changing service signature? Show your client code.

Comment: For instance, `PackedObject lpo = TableManager.proxy.GetFirstByQuery("Category", "");` works fine.

` List<PackedObject> list = TableManager.proxy.GetByQuery("Category", ""); ` - that isn't get a result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the other place.
While debugging  i found that `DataContractSerializer` refused to serialize `PackedObject` with null value in the Dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try making your class serialized.
2. Type cast result at client end.

Hope these two will solve your issue.

Comment: 1. As single object can pass through wcf i suppose it serialized normally.
2. Client end waits for response, so there is no object to cast.